# How to reset Prism for Xamarin.Forms (view) navigation stack?

Tags: navigation, stack, xamarin.forms, prism, reset

I am working around a conflict between Prism.Forms (v6.2.0) and the Xamarin Messaging Plugin (Xam.Plugins.Messaging v3.2.1), when trying to send an email from my app.

The following code - executed from one of my ViewModels:

```
using Plugin.Messaging;

if (MessagingPlugin.EmailMessenger.CanSendEmail)
{
    var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
        .To("test@testemail.com")
        .Subject("Email subject here!")
        .Body("Dear friend,\nI would like to say...\n\n\n")
        .Build();
    MessagingPlugin.EmailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
}
```

Produces this error - and the email-to-be-sent never shows up on the screen:

> Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController: 0x108fb4400> on <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_PageRenderer: 0x107de67c0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I believe that this happens because the iOS-specific part of the Messaging plugin has a `.GetVisibleViewController()` method that looks for a UIViewController with a visible view to display the email-to-be-sent on; and it is finding a view controller that iOS doesn't like.

I want to point out that I have almost identical code (to that shown above) running without problems in an MVVM-patterned Xamarin.Forms app that does not use Prism.Forms [edit: Brian L. makes the point below that this problem is probably not caused by Prism, and I tend to agree with him; it is more likely to be related to minor differences in the "navigation flow" between the two apps, even though the email building/sending code is the same].  When the `MessagingPlugin.EmailMessenger.SendEmail(email);` line executes, an email should pop up on the screen, with Recipient, Subject and Body as shown in the code; and with Send or Cancel buttons.  This works fine in the non-Prism Xamarin.Forms app.

So, I have worked around this problem enough to make the `.SendEmail(email)` method call work properly.  I have to pass my X.F page (i.e. the view for my viewmodel) to the iOS-specific project code to call `.CreateViewController()` on it.  I create a UIWindow with this new UIViewController as its RootViewController, and then make that window `.MakeKeyAndVisible()`.  I have tweaked the code of Xam.Plugins.Messaging to let me pass in a UIViewController to use. After the `.SendEmail(email)` method call happens, I dispose my newly created UIWindow; so that I don't see it after the email is sent or canceled.

This all works and allows me to use the Messaging plug-in's email sending capabilities as expected.

My only remaining problem is that navigation calls to my original ViewModel's navigationService instance (i.e. the ViewModel that was trying to send the email, using the code above) all fail after the email is sent.  Other functionality on my view/viewmodel works fine after the email is sent; but calls to `navigationService.GoBackAsync()` or `navigationService.NavigateAsync()` fail and produce a familiar error:

> Warning: Attempt to present <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper: 0x1359c21a0> on <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_PlatformRenderer: 0x133df9640> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I believe that what I want to do is reset my Prism NavigationService (view) stack, with something like this (code for Xamarin.Forms, without Prism):

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new HomePage(), Navigation.NavigationStack.First());
Navigation.PopToRootAsync(true);
```

But I don't see a way to do "navigation stack altering operations" like that with the Prism NavigationService. But maybe someone else does?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have almost identical code (to that shown above) running without problems in an MVVM-patterned Xamarin.Forms app that does not use Prism.Forms

Almost identical, is not identical.  I would like to mention that Prism does nothing special regarding MVVM.  It simply sets the Page.BindingContext for you. That's it.  So if you have it working with just a View and a VM in an app without Prism, there is no difference between using Prism.

To answer your question, to reset the navigation stack you simply use an absolute URI.

`NavigateAsync("myapp:///NavigationPage/MainPage")`

This is equivalent to `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`

Comment: Thank you Brian, will try that!

Comment: Thanks again, Brian.  That fixed my problem.  Instead of calling `navigationService.NavigateAsync("HomePage")`, I am now calling `navigationService.NavigateAsync("app:///HomePage")` - and things are working properly.  I looked for documentation about Prism Absolute URIs and it wasn't clear to me if "myapp" in your example above was a "magic string" - or needed to be customized for my app.  But it appears that it can be "anystring:///HomePage" and still work.  Let me know if that is wrong.  In case that helps future readers of this question/response...

Comment: That s correct.  Essentially, all you need is to provide a valid absolute URI.  Which can be anything from `http://www.myapp.com/MainPage`, to creating an actual `new Uri("some uri", UriKind.Abslute)`

Comment: @BrianLagunas Thanks for the solutions and explanation on how it works.

I am having two other doubts like lets say i navigated from Page A to B to C to D and then on some action in D if i need to remove only Page C, How can i Do that? And if i want to handle the android device back button and make that work as per my back button function how can i do that?? I was searching for this online for many days but back navigation is a huge problem creation for me. Can you please help me out with this..

Comment: If there are background tasks they are not canceled and continue to execute. So previous stack is not destroyed by this:)